# No Matching Function Call in a template class

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that reads in a text file and stores data into a class of objects called User. I then store the User objects into a templated class of dynamic arrays called MyList with a push_back function.

currently my MyList class looks like this

```
#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class type>
class MyList
{
public:
  MyList(); 
  ~MyList(); 
  int size() const;
  int at(int) const;
  void remove(int);
  void push_back(type);

private:
  type* List;
  int _size;
  int _capacity;
  const static int CAPACITY = 80;
};
```

and the function to pushback looks like this

```
template<class type>
void MyList<type>::push_back(type newfriend)
{

    if( _size >= _capacity){
         _capacity++;

    List[_size] = newfriend;
        size++;
    }
}
```

My User class is as follows

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#include "mylist.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>   

using namespace std;

class User
{
public:
  User();
  User(int id, string name, int year, int zip);
  ~User();

private:
  int id;
  string name;
  int age;
  int zip;
  MyList <int> friends;
};

#endif
```

finally, in my main function I declare the user MyList like this

```
MyList<User> object4;
```

and my call to push_back is as follows

```
User newuser(int id, string name, int age, int zip);
   object4.push_back(newuser);
```

All the data in the User class is valid,

currently im getting an error "no matching function for call to 'MyList::push_back(User) (&) (int, std:string, int, int)"

"note candidates are : void MyList::push_back(type) [with type = User]"

Answer (score 1):

You declare a function

```
User newuser(int id, string name, int age, int zip);
```

and try to `push_back` this function onto `object4`. But `object4` is declared to be a

```
MyList<User> object4;
```

not a `MyList<User (&) (int, std:string, int, int)>` of functions returning a `User`. That's the reason for the error message

> no matching function for call to "MyList::push_back(User (&) (int, std:string, int, int))"

If you want to create a `User` and append it to object4, you would do it like

```
User newuser(id, name, age, zip);
object4.push_back(newuser);
```

provided you have a constructor with these parameters.

Comment: Well I have a User object defined as an object containing an (int, name, int, int) so shouldn't i be able to use this format to store a User object into MyList?

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe i spent like an hour on such a petty error.